# What does InternalCoroutinesApi annotation means

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to the kotlin coroutines, I see some of the api's are annotated with `@InternalCoroutinesApi`.
From the official documentation it says that

> it should not be used outside of `kotlinx.coroutines`

I cannot clearly understand what does they mean.
Can anyone elaborate it?

Comment: It means they are don't intend for you to use these functions because they might change how they work or remove them in future updates.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but they mentioned it as should not be used outside of the coroutines. So can we use only in the kotlinx.coroutine?

Comment: You can't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This annotation

> marks declarations that are internal in coroutines API, which means
> that should not be used outside of kotlinx.coroutines, because their
> signatures and semantics will change between future releases without
> any warnings and without providing any migration aids.

Source: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-internal-coroutines-api/