# How to remove annotation @InternalCoroutinesApi In android

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have watched and read many tutorial on How to use Room persistence library with coroutines but whenever I use coroutine in my file it forces me to annotate my code with @InternalCoroutineApi but in the tutorial they don't need to annotate anything.
Now I'm wanted to know
1. What does this annotation means?
2. Why it is necessary?
3. How can I avoid this?
Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229037/what-does-internalcoroutinesapi-annotation-means) answer doesn't help me either.
below is the how I created my data base and my build.gradle file

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.internal.synchronized

@Database(entities = [Post::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class PostRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): PostDao
    companion object{
        //Companion object provide the same functionality as the Static keyword in java
        @Volatile
        private var DATABASE_INSTANCE :PostRoomDatabase? = null

        @InternalCoroutinesApi
        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : PostRoomDatabase{
            val tempInstance = DATABASE_INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
            return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PostRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "post_database"
                ).build()
                DATABASE_INSTANCE = instance;
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vijay.bhadolia.seed"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //Circular images
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    //Room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"


    def coroutines_version = "1.3.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
}
```

Comment: What is your `kotlin_version`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it says 1.3.72-release-Studio3.6-1

Comment: No, I meant the variable you are using in your `build.gradle` file (generally it is declared in your top level `build.gradle` file, which you have not included here).

Comment: @ianhanniballake The version in top level file is also same **ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your imports say:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.internal.synchronized
```

Which is the internal API that it is complaining about. You should not be importing anything for the synchronized keyword, so simply remove that import line.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The issues goes beyond a wrong import and arise every time you import something already marked with @InternalCoroutinesApi. A real nightmare.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be importing any API marked with `InternalCoroutinesApi`, so it always the wrong thing to do so. They're internal for a reason: not for external usage.

Comment: I get it in my tests, we use the runTest function from package kotlinx.coroutines.test.  Wondering how to remove this warning in the gradle for tests